# faint white smoke, burning smell and poor acceleration

Tags: chevrolet, truck, silverado

I have a 1998 V8 5.7 Chevy Silverado C1500 RWD, my problem is I did have a small wreck in this truck and have been replacing parts on it, I hit a ditch and the right front tire hit a metal culvert pretty hard a 40 mph,I have replaced a great many parts on  it and it's now in driving condition,I have now noticed that when i'm driving it struggles going up hill and the RPM's drops down fast when going up hills and my truck comes to a near stand still, as i'm driving home I noticed a burning smell and I pulled over to check under the hood and could see white smoke coming from behind the transmission, I just had the transmission pan,filter and fluid changed out.

Comment: Sounds like may be a plugged convertor.